A problem involving the recursive sequence $ x_{n+2} = \lambda x_n + ( 1 - \lambda ) x_{n+1}$ , where $ 0 < \lambda < 1 $
This is from the book called Problems in Real Analysis by Charalombos D Aliprantis and Owen Burkinshaw, 2nd Edition.
In page $30$, Problem $4.20$:
Let $\infty < a < b < \infty$ and $ 0 < \lambda < 1 $. Define the sequence $\{ x_n\}$ by $x_1 = a$, $x_2 =b$ and
$$ x_{n+2} = \lambda x_n + ( 1 - \lambda ) x_{n+1}$$
Show that $\{ x_n\}$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$ and find its limit.
The book first rewrite $ x_{n+2} = \lambda x_n + ( 1 - \lambda ) x_{n+1} = \lambda x_n + x_{n+1} - \lambda  x_{n+1}$ in the form  $x_{n+2} -  x_{n+1} = \lambda ( x_n - x_{n+1})$. So $$ |x_{n+2} -  x_{n+1}| = \lambda | x_{n+1} - x_{n}|$$
By Problem $4.15$ in page $28$:
$\big($Assume that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ satisfies
$$|x_{n+1} - x_n| \leq \alpha |x_n - x_{n-1}|$$
for $n=2,3,4,...$ andd some fixed $0 < \alpha < 1$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence.$\big)$
We see that $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence.
The book states that we cant get the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ by taking limits of both sides. So the book decides to use a different method to derive the limit of $\{x_n\}$.
First set $\mu = 1 - \lambda$. Then the book prove that
$$x_1 < x_3 < ... < x_{2n+1} < x_{2n} < x_{2n-2} < ... < x_2$$
holds for each $n \in \mathbb N$ , by mathematical induction.
Next, the book sets $d_n = x_{2n} - x_{2n-1}$ , it says that it is easy to verify that
$$d_{n+1} = \lambda \mu d_n$$
But I cant derive this equation using the given formulas. The book also states that it is also easy to derive the two following formulas:
$$x_{2n+1} = x_{2n-1} + \mu d_n$$
$$x_{2n+2} = x_{2n} - \lambda^2 d_n$$
Because I can't derive the first one , I stop verifying these formulas and stop reading the proof. But I see that the book gives a final answer
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \frac{\lambda^2 a + \mu b}{1- \lambda \mu}$$
I decided to come up with another proof, inspired by the post Find the limit of the sequence $y_n$ defined by $x_{n}$.
My Proof :
Since $x_{n+2} = \lambda x_n + ( 1 - \lambda ) x_{n+1}$ can be rewritten in the form $$x_{n+2} -  x_{n+1} = \lambda ( x_n - x_{n+1})$$
Set $y_n = x_{n+1} - x_n$, then the above formula can be rewritten in the form $$x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} - \lambda y_n$$
So
$y_1 = x_2 - x_1= b-a$, which gives $$x_3 = x_2 - \lambda y_1 = (1-\lambda) b + \lambda a$$
$y_2 = x_3 - x_2 =(1 - \lambda) b + \lambda a -b = -\lambda b +\lambda a$, which gives $$x_4 = x_3 - \lambda y_2 = (1-\lambda) b + \lambda a - \lambda (-\lambda b +\lambda a) = (1-\lambda + \lambda^2) b - (-\lambda + \lambda^2) a$$
$y_3 = x_4 - x_3 =(1 - \lambda + \lambda^2) b - (-\lambda + \lambda^2) a -(1-\lambda) b - \lambda a = \lambda^2 b -\lambda^2 a$, which gives $$x_5 = x_4 - \lambda y_3 = (1-\lambda + \lambda^2) b - (-\lambda + \lambda^2) a - \lambda (\lambda^2 b -\lambda^2 a) = (1-\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3) b - (-\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3) a$$
.
.
.
Hence we have that
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} 
&= (1-\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 + ...+ (- \lambda )^n ) b - (-\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 + ...+ (- \lambda )^n) a \\
&= (1-\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 + ...+ (- \lambda )^n ) b - ( 1 -\lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 + ...+ (- \lambda )^n) a + a \\
&= \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1-(-\lambda)} b - \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1-(-\lambda)} a +a \\
&= \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1+\lambda} b - \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1+\lambda} a +a \\
\end{align}
And therefore $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n+2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big( \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1+\lambda} b - \frac{1 - (- \lambda )^{n+1}}{1+\lambda} a +a \big) = \frac{b-a}{1-\lambda} + a = \frac{b + \lambda a}{1+ \lambda}$$
Questions:

Is the formula given by the book : $$d_{n+1} = \lambda \mu d_n$$ wrong? Or am I too stupid or incapable of doing simple mathematics any more?

Is my solution correct? Because it is different from the book. If it is wrong ,where is the error?


Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Relax! As far as I can see, $d_{n+1}=\lambda \mu d_n$ is wrong.

You could heve made it  faster but your last result (before Questions is pefectly coeerect. In fact, $ d_{n+1}=\lambda^2 , d_n$

The recurrence relation has constant coefficients. The general procedure is to solve the characteristic equation $z^2=\lambda +(1-\lambda)z,$ which yields $z=1$ or $z=-\lambda.$ Then the general solution is of the form $c_1+c_2(-\lambda)^n.$

Let us solve the following with slight change in notations.
$$X_{n+2}=t X_{n}+(1-t)X_{n+1}=0, 0<t<1$$
Let $X_n=z^n$, then we get
$$z^2-(1-t)z-t=0\implies  z=-t,1$$
So $$X_n=C_1 (-t)^n+C_2(1)^n,$$
where $C_1,C_2$ can be calculated as $X_1=a,X_2=b$ are specified.
Then $$C_1=\frac{b-a}{t(1+t)}, C_2=\frac{(b+at)}{1+t},0 <t <1.$$
This gives $X_{\infty}=C_2.$

The equation is $z^2-(1-t)z-t=0.$

@Ryszard Szwarc Thanks, I have edited my solution now.
